# How to call constants in java?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

This question might sound kinda weird but, how do i call constants in java? The thing is that i'm playing around with AlertDialog android class. Since this class have protected constructors i cannot call them in my activity class where i'm creating my dialog. So i've made a child AlertDialog class and made its constructors public, like this:

```
public class TestAlert extends AlertDialog {

public TestAlert(Context context) {
    super(context); 
}   

public TestAlert(Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);      
}
}
```

And then I've created dialog like that:

```
TestAlert ta = new TestAlert(con, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
    ta.setMessage("Hello");     
    ta.show();
```

The strange thing here is that this code is wrong: `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`
and i don't have idea why.

From [Android developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK) page about AlertDialog class we can clearly see that these themes are constants. (public, static, final ). Since they are static they should be called with class name, followed by a dot. They are public also, so there should be no problem. But strange thing is that i cannot do that. But if I pass number instead constant name, its working, like this:

```
new TestAlert(con, 2);
```

p.s: I know I should use `AlertDialog.Builder` for building dialogues. But lets call that I'm "exploring" .

Help appriciated.

Comment: "Here, Constant!  Here boy!"

Comment: What do you mean by "this code is wrong"?

Comment: What API version are those constants defined for what what API version are you targeting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't "call" constants, you refer to them. The way you're referring to them is fine for `public static` constants like these, and your `TestAlert` constructor is correctly accepting the second argument as an `int`, so that's fine.

Those theme constants were added in API Level 14. If you're compiling against/targeting an earlier API, they won't exist.

Comment: Ok, now..i'm feeling like i should kill myself. You are right.
I was targeting API LEVEL 8. Thank you!

Comment: @ rootpanthera: :-) We've all done stuff like that, don't beat yourself up.